# Insert data not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm not sure if below the code is correct, I just tried to insert data not in another table, I'm not sure if I can use two columns in brackets `where ([Event],[Event Start  DateTime])`

```
 insert into CPEvents3 select * from CPEvents1 where ([Event],[Event Start  DateTime]) not in 
 (select [Event], [Event Start DateTime] from CPEvents3)
```

Thanks, S

Comment: OT: If this is under your control I'd avoid column names like `[Event Start  DateTime]`. In this special case I'm not even sure, if the *DateTime* is really part of the column's name or the data type taken from the declaration... Best are plain names without spaces. You might use underscores...

Answer (score 1):

in this way we need to write

```
INSERT INTO CPEVENTS3
([Event],[Event Start  DateTime]) 
select [Event],
[Event Start  DateTime]
 FROM CPEvents1 CP 
 where NOT EXISTS 
 (
SELECT [Event], [Event Start DateTime] 
from CPEvents3 
WHERE CP.[Event] = [Event])
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO CPEVENTS3
([Event],
[Event Start  DateTime]
) 
select [Event],[Event Start  DateTime]FROM CPEvents1 
 EXCEPT 
select [Event],[Event Start  DateTime]FROM CPEvents3
```

Comment: `Not exists` misses predicate for `[Event Start  DateTime]`

Comment: to Ivan Starostin: what is missed for Not exists, how whole query should be? thanks

Comment: @JoeGreen `EXCEPT` example is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way also

```
 insert into CPEvents3 
 select * from CPEvents1 where 
 [Event] not in (select [Event] from CPEvents3)
 and [Event Start  DateTime] not in (select [Event Start  DateTime] from CPEvents3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use an [outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), to find those records that appear in one table but not the other.  These can then be inserted.

```
-- Add new records to CPEvents3.
INSERT INTO CPEvents3 
    (
        [Event],
        [Event Start  DateTime]     
    )
SELECT 
    c1.[Event],
    c1.[Event Start  DateTime]
FROM 
    CPEvents1 AS c1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CPEvents3 AS c3     ON  c3.[Event]                  = c1.[Event]
                                            AND c3.[Event Start  DateTime]  = c1.[Event Start DateTime]
WHERE
    c3.[Event] IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query it will works fine

```
INSERT INTO CPEvents3 
SELECT *
FROM CPEvents1 LEFT OUTER JOIN CPEvents3 
ON  CPEvents3.[Event]= CPEvents1.[Event]
AND CPEvents3.[Event Start  DateTime]  = CPEvents1.[Event Start DateTime]
WHERE  CPEvents3.[Event] IS NULL
```

TO select Data Stored in a table And not found in another one using compare on One or more Column you can use left join on these Columns and setting a conidtion that one of the joins columns from the second table is null. So the query return only data found in the first table and not found in the other one

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it answers the question. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot compare in where two columns at a time. You need to make for each column a condition like this:

```
insert into CPEvents3 
select * from CPEvents1 c1 where 
     [Event] not in (select [Event] from CPEvents3) and 
  [Event Start  DateTime] not in (select [Event Start DateTime] from CPEvents3)
```

It is good practice to specify the columns in the insert and select list.

Comment: These two queries would give different output, both examples would return wrong result.